# Почему нельзя открыть профиль некоторых пользователей?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, страница-учётной-записи, удаление-ответов, удаление-профиля

У таких пользователей не открывается профиль, нет обозначения репутации под вопросом, одно имя.
 [image] 
Что это значит? Пользователь удален? Но тогда получается, и его вопрос должен быть удален.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сообщение после публикации согласно лицензии CC-BY-SA, принятой на сайте, не являются собственностью автора, а вступают в коллективное владение, хотя, конечно, имя автора остаётся под сообщением.

В случае же удаления профиля пользователя, его имя заменяется на user<идентификатор> и никакой другой информации о пользователе уже не остаётся. Поэтому и ссылку делать не на что.